# My Fragment Layout File Fails to Display the Button When I Run the App

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Please know i a using a constrain layout. The views are properly constrained.

On the layout editor preview , both the buttons and textviews are visible. When I ran the up the textviews are visible but the button is invisible.

See attached layout code and screenshots.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_welcome_instructions"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/welcome_text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shoe_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_mono"
            android:text="@string/store_text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_welcome_instructions" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/instructions_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="264dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/welcome_button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Thanks in advance.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was Margin Bottom.  I have instead used Margin Top.